# Maximize L2 norm of a vector under linear constraints?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

I have following problem,

\begin{align}
&\max_{x \in R^n} |x|_2^2 \newline
 \mathrm{s.t}\quad &Ax \leq b
\end{align}

$|.|_2$ indicates L2 norm of a vector.

I see the problem is NP-hard, and there are some literature on this. Can anyone suggest me any well performing algorithms to find the near optimal solution?

Comment: can you comment on the dimensions of A?

Comment: Have a look at [GloMIQO](http://helios.princeton.edu/GloMIQO/). Writing down the first-order conditions leads to an interesting  [MIP formulation](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/06/solving-non-convex-qp-problems-as-mip.html).

Comment: @LinAlg: My problem's dimensions is ~ 400

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: I see all the quadratic problems deals with only convex problems. But in our case, the problem is not convex!!

Comment: The links I gave are about non-convex QPs. Also note that Cplex has a global QP solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: Thank you very much for the link :-). Where can I download [GloMIQO](http://helios.princeton.edu/GloMIQO/index.html) (Global Mixed-Integer Quadratic Optimizer)? Is it same as [GAMS](http://www.gams.com/)? Can it solve **400** dimensional problem?

Comment: GloMIQO is available through Princeton University or through [gams](http://www.gams.com). You can also try Baron which you actually can try online on [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html). 400 variables is not small but doable depending on the rest of the model.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: I see [GloMIQO](http://helios.princeton.edu/GloMIQO/index.html) is heavily [priced](https://www.gams.com/sales/academicp.pdf) (>$2000 for academic version!). Is there any cheaper tools available?

Comment: Here are some other options: Baron (free online via NEOS), Couenne (free), MIP formulation via FOC (any MIP solver), Cplex (free for academics)